# what is the use of alt and thread-alt classes in wordpress comments?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am reading from codex http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Plugins_and_Themes_to_2.7/Enhanced_Comment_Display

> thread-odd, thread-even, and thread-alt classes are the same as the
>   odd/even/alt classes, but these only apply to the top level of each
>   set of comments and replies

i get the use of even and odd but not alt.If alt and odd/even are the same,why do they keep appearing in comments even for the most latest version of wordpress?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has to do with backwards compatibility issues. Maybe first their was nothing / `alt` where `even` / `odd` is add latter on. So now you have `even` + nothing / `odd` + `alt`.

For the same reason `thread-odd, thread-even, and thread-alt` are still their while you don't need them. Cause for example `thread-odd` will be the same selector as `depth-1.odd`.